# Visual Studio plugin to highlight current source file

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Is there any Visual Studio plugin that would highlight a source code file in solution explorer where debugger is at current time ? Or is it a stupid question ?

Comment: It should just do this by default. At least it will select the file the debugger is currently broken in.  Are you not seeing this?

Comment: There is a setting you have to turn on for older visual studio versions.

Comment: @JaredPar, I'm using a VS 2010 and don't see that. I actually never saw that on any of the machines I've worked on so far (all VS 2010).

Comment: @Chuchelo generally whenever a file is open for editting it will be selected in Solution Explorer.  The debugger just inherits this by virtue of it opening the file.  It sounds like it's either not opening a file that's a part of the solution (same contents, different path) or that something is fairly wrong there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its in Tools -> Options ->Project and Solutions -> General ->Track active item in solution explorer.